# How can I prove this??

Tags: calculus, limits

> If $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \ell$ and $\exists\delta > 0$ such that $f(x)\geq 0\;\forall x \in (a − \delta, a + \delta)$.
> Prove that $\ell \geq 0$.

So I know that this has to happen because if the function is all the time $\geq 0$, then the limit can't be $\leq 0$, because that would say that there is a moment where the function is $\le 0$, and that is a contradiction with the formulation.

So how can I translate this to a demonstration? Because I think that my argumentation can't be call a demonstration.

Comment: sick title… Care to make it more descriptive tho?

Comment: Suppose it is not true.  Suppose $l>0.$  Then $|f(x) - l| = |l|+|f(x)|$ in the limit definition choose $\epsilon < |l|$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proof by contradiction seems like a way to go here.

Suppose, for the purpose of contradiction, that $l < 0.$ Then we have $-\frac{l}{2} > 0$ so by the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of a limit, there exists some $\delta' > 0$
such that
$$ |x-a| < \delta' \implies |f(x) - l| < -\frac{l}{2} \tag{*}. $$
Furthermore, by the hypothesis, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that
$$ |x-a| < \delta \implies f(x) \geq 0 \tag{**}. $$

Now let $\delta'' = min(\delta,\delta').$ Then
$(a - \delta'', a + \delta'') \subset (a-\delta, a+\delta)$ and
$(a - \delta'', a + \delta'') \subset (a-\delta', a+\delta')$ so both (*) and (**) are true. Thus, for all $x \in (a- \delta'', a+\delta''), $ we have

$$ |f(x) - l| < -\frac{l}{2} $$
which is equivalent to
$$ \frac{3l}{2} < f(x) < \frac{l}{2} < 0 $$
contradicting (**).

Answer (score 0):

You can prove this by reductio ad absurdum. Suppose the limit $l$ is strictly less than $0$. ($l < 0$). Then by the definition of the limit for any $\epsilon$ greater than $0$ there exists some $\delta_1$ greater than $0$ such that for any $x$ in the open interval $(a - delta1, a + delta1)$ the value of $f(x)$ is in the open interval $(l - \epsilon, l + \epsilon)$. This statement is true for any epsilon, in particular for $\epsilon = -0.5l$. Therefore $f(x)$ is in the interval $(1.5l, 0.5l)$. Because the limit is negative $f(x)$ is strictly less than $0$, for any $x$ in $(a - \delta_1, a + \delta_1)$. This means that there exists $V$(a neighborhood of the number $a$) such that if $x$ is in $V$, $f(x)$ is less than $0$ which contradicts the hypothesis that there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $f(x) > 0$ for $a - \delta < x < a + \delta$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

Assume $l<0.$

Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ converge to $a$ then $\lim_{x_n \rightarrow a} f(x_n) =l.$

Choose $0< \epsilon < |l/4|:$

There exists a $\Delta$ s.t.

$|x-a|<\Delta$ implies $|f(x) - l|< \epsilon.$

There exists a $n_0$ s.t. for $n \ge n_0$

$|x_n - a|< \Delta$ implies $|f(x_n) - l|< \epsilon.$

Choose $d=min(\delta, \Delta).$

There exists a $N \ge n_0$ s.t. for $n\ge N$

$|x_n-a|< d$ implies $|f(x_n) - l|< \epsilon$, a contradiction.